# Sql query taking long time with inner join

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, inner-join

I am supposed to write a query which requires joining 3 tables.
The query designed by me works fine, but it takes a lot of time to execute.

```
SELECT v.LinkID,  r.SourcePort, r.DestPort, r.NoOfBytes, r.StartTime , r.EndTime, r.Direction, r.nFlows
FROM LINK_TBL v 
INNER JOIN NODEIF_TBL n 
INNER JOIN RAW_TBL r ON 
    r.RouterIP=n.ifipaddress 
    and n.NodeNumber=v.orinodenumber 
    and v.oriIfIndex=r.OriIfIndex;
```

Is there any issue w.r.t performance in this query ?

Comment: You don't have any join conditions for `NODEIF_TBL`

Comment: @Phil. Hi, I am matching a 2 columns from NODEIF_TBL with 2 different columns from the remaining tables, I think this is joining the tables, right ? Or did you mean to convey something else. I am not that good in sql.

Comment: See the below answers, they are all correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one put the on conditions in the joins

```
SELECT v.LinkID,  r.SourcePort, r.DestPort, r.NoOfBytes, r.StartTime , r.EndTime, r.Direction, r.nFlows
FROM LINK_TBL v 
INNER JOIN NODEIF_TBL n ON (n.NodeNumber=v.orinodenumber )
INNER JOIN RAW_TBL r ON (r.RouterIP=n.ifipaddress   and v.oriIfIndex=r.OriIfIndex)
```

Comment: Hi Dianuj, The o/p time is 50.25 seconds where as original query gives 49.89 s. But I think you way of joining is what should be used always. Thanks

Comment: columns of your table does have proper indexes ?

Comment: No. I have never done indexing. Maybe, that would help I guess.

Comment: yes you have to index your column see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Yup, I will try indexing. Just tell me one thing. Is it compulsory to index all the tables ? Also, Do I need to do indexing everytime new data is inserted into table ?

Comment: Hey, I added INDEX only on 1 table and now the time is 0.62s. This is damm fast !! . Thank you guys.

Comment: @Ajit you are welcome indexes are not necessary but one should have to take care about the speed of mysql so try to index the columns which are in the `WHERE` `AND` conditions

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT v.LinkID,  r.SourcePort, r.DestPort, r.NoOfBytes, r.StartTime , r.EndTime, r.Direction, r.nFlows
FROM LINK_TBL v 
INNER JOIN NODEIF_TBL n ON
    n.NodeNumber=v.orinodenumber 
INNER JOIN RAW_TBL r ON 
    r.RouterIP=n.ifipaddress 
and v.oriIfIndex=r.OriIfIndex;
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, there is a marginal improvement with your query. It is 49.47s vs 49.89s. Can put some more light on it ? Also, can you tell me that instead on INNER JOIN, I directly write a where clause like T1.a=T2.b and T2.c=T3.d then what will be the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

The join order is somewhat weird. I don't work with mysql so maybe it is just some unique way to join, but usually you join like:

```
FROM 
    a
    INNER JOIN b ON a.id1 = b.id2
    INNER JOIN c ON b.id3 = c.id4
```

Since you are using INNER JOIN this way you first filter out a with b joins and only then use the remaining join to filter out thus saving a lot of comparison actions. Imagine each table has 1 thousand rows. When you add c this becomes 1 million comparisons. Meanwhile with my example it would only be 1000 + 1000 comparisons instead of 1000 * 1000.

Comment: Thanks man, you have explained it very well. Will, keep this in mind henceforth. I also need to Index my tables as suggested by Dianuj.