# How to improve an indexed inner join query Mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-performance

this is my first question ever on forum so do not hesitate to tell me if there is anything to improve in my question.

I have a big database with two tables

- "visit" (6M rows) which basically stores each visit on a website

```
    | visitdate           | city     |
    ----------------------------------
    | 2014-12-01 00:00:02 | Paris    |
    | 2015-01-03 00:00:02 | Marseille|
```

- "cityweather" (1M rows) that stores weather infos 3 times a day for a lot of cities

```
    | weatherdate           | city     |
    ------------------------------------
    | 2014-12-01 09:00:02   | Paris    |
    | 2014-12-01 09:00:02   | Marseille|
```

I precise that there can be cities in the table visit that are not in cityweather and vice versa and I need to only take citties that are common to both tables.

I first had a big query that I tried to run and failed and I am therefore trying to go back to the simplest possible query joining those two table but the performance are terrible.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t.city)) 
FROM visit t 
INNER JOIN cityweather d
ON t.city = d.city;
```

I precise that both tables are indexed on the column city and I already did the `COUNT(DISTINCT(city))` on both tables independantly and it takes less than one second for each.

You can find below te result of the `EXPLAIN` on this query :

```
    | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref          | rows         | Extra                    |
    ----------------------------------
    | 1  |  SIMPLE     | d     | index | idx_city      | idx_city | 303     | NULL         | 1190553      | Using where; Using index |
    | 1  |  SIMPLE     | t     | ref   | Idxcity       | Idxcity  | 303     | meteo.d.city | 465          | Using index              |
```

You will find below the table information and especialy the engine for both tables :

**visit**

```
    | Name  | Engine | Version | Row_Format | Rows    | Avg_row_len | Data_len  | Max_data_len | Index_len | Data_free |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | visit | InnoDB | 10      | Compact    | 6208060 | 85          | 531628032 | 0            | 0         | 0         |
```

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE output` :

```
    CREATE TABLE
`visit` (
`productid` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`visitdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`minute` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`hour` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`weekday` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`quotation` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`weathertype` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`temp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`pressure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`humidity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `Idxvisitdate` (`visitdate`),
KEY `Idxcity` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**citiweather**

```
    | Name        | Engine | Version | Row_Format | Rows    | Avg_row_len | Data_len  | Max_data_len | Index_len | Data_free |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | cityweather | InnoDB | 10      | Compact    | 1190553 | 73          | 877670784 | 0            | 0         | 30408704  |
```

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE output` :

```
CREATE TABLE `cityweather` (
`city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lat` decimal(13,9) DEFAULT NULL,
`lon` decimal(13,9) DEFAULT NULL,
`weatherdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`temp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`pressure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`humidity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `Idxweatherdate` (`weatherdate`),
KEY `idx_city` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have the feeling that the problem comes from the `type = index` and the `ref = NULL` but I have no idea how to fix it...

[You can find here a close question that did not help me solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095854/sql-query-taking-long-time-with-inner-join/18095941#18095941?newreg=4f28b5cc77bf4319beba994bcc7eb1f3)

Thanks !

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Where/what is the error? Can you show desired result in table format?

Comment: My problem is that the query goes for hours (I allowed 60 000sec) and then crashes...

What do you mean by MyIsam or InnoDb ? I am very new to Mysql...

Comment: and where from u get "Using where; Using index" if there is no WHERE-clause in the query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d35d/3

Comment: I updated the question to add the status of each table. They are both InnoDb.

Comment: I have no idea why their is a where in it...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete DDL for these tables, including all indexes, constraints, etc. Thanks.

Comment: I made the changes you asked Bob, is that ok or do you need other informations ?

Comment: Just for curiousity.. try to run this query and see if the time ro run changes: `SELECT t.city, count(t.city) FROM visit t INNER JOIN cityweather d ON t.city = d.city group by t.city`

Comment: Only took 1 second... Nice intuition, but I really don't understand why then the other query takes so long...

Comment: Check the numbers -- Sometimes a JOIN inflates a COUNT.

Comment: That may have run fast because everything was cached.  Conversely, the original attempt may have run slow because of having to read all the data from disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is so slow because the index you use can't get the number of lines down to a faster amount. See your `EXPLAIN` output: It tells you that the use of the index on city (`idx_city`) in table `cityweather` will require 1.190.553 lines to process. Joining by `city` to your `visit` table will require again 465 lines from that table.

As a result your database will have to process 1.190.553 x 465 lines.

As your query is you can't improve its performance. But you can modify your query e.g. by adding a condition on your visiting data to narrow the results down. Try all kinds of `EXISTS` queries as well.

**Update**

Perhaps this helps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTbl 
SELECT distinct city as city from cityweather;

ALTER TABLE tmpTbl Add index adweerf (city);

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(city)) FROM visit WHERE city in (SELECT city from tmpTbl);
```

Comment: Thanks Benvorth, if you just change in your answer `SELECT * FROM visit` by `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(city)) FROM visit` I mark the answer as accepted

Comment: It only took 9 seconds :)
I think I am starting to get how to design efficient queries thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

Since `IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes poorly, change

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(city)) FROM visit WHERE city in (SELECT city from tmpTbl);
```

to

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT city FROM cityweather ) x
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM visit
                   WHERE city = x.city );
```

Both tables need (and have) an index on `city`.  I'm pretty sure it is better to put the smaller table (cityweather) in the `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Other points:

- Every InnoDB table really should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- You could save a lot of space by using `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte), etc, instead of using 4-byte INT always.
- 9 decimal places for lat/lng is excessive for cities, and takes 12 bytes.  I vote for DECIMAL(4,2)/(5,2) (1.6km / 1mi resolution; 5 bytes) or DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4) (16m/52ft, 7 bytes).

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks. First time working with gps coordinates :)

I just don't get what you mean by `PRIMARY KEY` because I don't have any possible `KEY` in my tables... Or am i mistaking the use of it ?

Comment: Is the combination `(weatherdate, city)` unique throughout `cityweather`?  If so, you could say `PRIMARY KEY(weatherdate, city)` and drop the index on `weatherdate`.